# Custom Package/Theme for Admin module that falls back to default package?

Tags: magento-1.8

How Do i ask magento to use a **custom layout package/theme** for my **custom admin module**?

**What's the Structure and content** that i have to include inside **local.xml** file if i have to use it for defining a custom design package?

Please tell if there are also **other ways of doing this**..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

add these lines in **app/etc/local.xml** (or) {**yourPKG/yourModule/etc/config.xml**} file **under `<config>` tag**

Its better If you add it inside your module's Config folder for the reasons specied by @Marius under the comments..

```
 <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>MyCustomTheme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
</stores>
```

where **MyCustomTHeme** is your theme folder inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/MyCustomTheme`

This method takes your MyCustomTheme as default theme and **uses FallBack for any layout that is not found**.

Adding the above line's inside `app/etc/config.xml` showed no effect.

And **changing the Package** folder name from default to "`myNewPAckage`" had **overridden** the default and **required me to copy whole default** into `myNewPAckage` folder **else nothing worked**.

So, to have FallBack effect, **keep the package as default and give theme as  `yourCustomTheme`.**

Comment: +1 for this with a minor comment. You shouldn't add this in `app/etc/local.xml`. Usually this file is not copied between instances (dev, staging, prod) and you might lose the functionality. Use the `config.xml` file of a custom module.

Comment: I thought that i would override the default admin layout folder, but it actually works, we can add these lines in our modules config file too. :) thanks

Comment: @user3151033 it works because Magento will combine the XML from every extension's `etc/config.xml` together, along with `app/etc/local.xml` to a single all inclusive XML configuration. `app/etc/local.xml` is loaded first, AND then loaded again last. The reason for this is so that it can receive it's initial configuration values, and so that it also has the last say in configuration (by loading it again always last).