# How to using Fall-Back Hierarchy change a file in:

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, theme-fallback

How to using Fall-Back Hierarchy, properly modify a file eg: **/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml**

*My theme is: 
Package: **Ultimo**
Theme: **default***

I tried save modified file into these:
/app/design/adminhtml/**ultimo**/**default**/template/login.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/**delault**/**ultimo**/template/login.phtml

non of these working, what do I do wrong?
Please advise

Comment: See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14111/custom-package-theme-for-admin-module-that-falls-back-to-default-package

Comment: Is there a custom theme for the admin or just the frontend?

Answer (score 4):

### Background

Magento introduced the **base/default** theme in CE 1.4 and made this an absolute fallback (independent of configuration). Prior to this the "main" distribution theme was **default/default**. Developing third-party modules was a big mess before 1.4 because you couldn't know how the user's themes were configured. Since this time one always puts "new" assets in **base/default**.

However, Magento (for some reason, perhaps due to internal testing tools) never moved the adminhtml theme from **default/default** which stinks because it means you always have to specify a custom theme for adminhtml in case of changes. This issue is even further complicated by the core distribution of a [third-party module with custom theme elements](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/code/community/Find/Feed/etc/config.xml#L124) requiring Magento to ship *with a custom theme already specified*:

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <default>ultimo</default><!-- or "anna" or whatever -->
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Thankfully this module was removed from core distribution after 1.6.

### Answer

For your 1.9 install, assuming it does not have a legacy `Find_Feed` module, you have a few options in general. For you specifically though you need to see if Ultimo theme is making customizations to the Magento admin theme settings using one of these methods:

1. You can move the entire adminhtml theme from **default/default** to **base/default** (I've tested, it works without a hitch), and then you can place customized files in **default/default** as they will be picked up without additional configuration. However, this is risky as an upgrade will replace the files under **default/default**. So, probably don't do this.
2. You can specify a custom theme via configuration...

   ```
   <stores>
       <admin>
           <design>
               <theme>
                   <default>find</default>
               </theme>
           </design>
       </admin>
   </stores>
   ```

   (Note that this will *add* a fallback level *above* **default/default**, i.e. the system will resolve theme paths first under **default/ultimo** and then under **default/default**.)
3. ...or via the new `theme.xml` file, amply explained by [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes).

You could also combine 1 & 2. and specify a new package (this would be my approach if the Ultimo theme has customizations and is not setting adminhtml theme or package in some crazy way.