# Translate attribute note

Tags: attributes, localisation, customer-attribute, custom-attributes

I've added a custom attribute to the customer. I've added a *note* to clarify the attribute.

The installer for the attribute:

```
<?php
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend' => '',
    'label' => 'Custom Label',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'source' => 'module_namespace/eav_entity_attribute_source_customcustomerattr',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'default' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique' => false,
    'note' => 'Instruction text',
));
```

I've added a csv to the module which works for the *Custom Label* but it doesn't work for the *Instruction text*

Magento prints the note in : `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml`

```
<?php $_note = $_element->getNote();
// other
<?php if ($_note): ?>
    <p class="note<?php echo $_class ? " {$_class}-note" : ''?>" id="note_<?php echo $_element->getId()?>">
        <span><?php echo $_note ?></span>
    </p>
<?php endif ?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything.
The problem is that the `note` field of the attributes are never translated.
The tabs with attributes are generated via the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes`.
you will find this `$this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, array('gallery'));`.
This line creates the inputs for each attribute.
If you search for the `_setFieldset` method definition, you will find it in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` and you will see this in it's body.

```
         $element = $fieldset->addField($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $fieldType,
                array(
                    'name'      => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'label'     => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                    'class'     => $attribute->getFrontend()->getClass(),
                    'required'  => $attribute->getIsRequired(),
                    'note'      => $attribute->getNote(),
                )
            )
```

Notice the line `'note'      => $attribute->getNote(),`.  The attribute note does not get translated.
Also in the template you mentioned, the note is used as it is:  `$_note = $_element->getNote()`.
You have 2 options here.
one is to rewrite the `_setFieldset` method and translate the note using `Mage::helper('catalog')->__($attribute->getNote())`, but this involves a lot of work.
The second option is to create a new admin theme that contains only the template you mentioned and instead of `$_note = $_element->getNote();` use

```
$_note = $this->__($_element->getNote());
```

[Here is a tutorial on how to change the admin theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14112/146)

Comment: Thanks I know enough. I'll rewrite the `_setFieldset` as it will keep the files within the module.