# How to overwrite adminhtml sales order renderer?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, overrides, sales

I am a beginner in magento. I needed to add notice to admin for some special product. But I have added my modifications to core files.
I added my code to,

```
app / design / adminhtml / default / default / template / sales / order / view / items / renderer / default.phtml
```

Cause I was able to access some product attributes there and it was the best place I found.
Now I just would like to use a copy of this in,

```
app / design / adminhtml / default / my_newtheme /templates/..../default.phtml
```

and use it in my xml,

```
app / design / adminhtml / default / my_newtheme /layout/..../sales.phtml
```

But it does not work....

It is a small change for me , not some huge one that i need special block and some observer or so...or do I?

Answer (score 1):

To override the `default package/theme` in adminhtml, you have to specify it to magento either in `app/etc/local.xml` or in a config.xml file of your custom module. Once you did that, your files copied from

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/

to

> app/design/adminhtml/my_package/my_theme/

will be processed.

More details [in this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14111/custom-package-theme-for-admin-module-that-falls-back-to-default-package).